# url redirection with get parameter Apatche htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello I have a url that is like that :

```
www.mysite.com/activation.php?token=d4ba10b14dedc7e7e7338ee8251670fa
```

What I would like to have is something like that :

```
www.mysite.com/Activation/Token/d4ba10b14dedc7e7e7338ee8251670fa
```

How can I do that please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this rule in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Activation/Token/([^/]+)$ /activation.php?token=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It worked like that : RewriteRule Activation/Token/([^/]+)$ activation.php?token=$1 [L]    Thanks